# Android draw curved path Animation on canvas

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas

How should I do a curved path draw animation in Android canvas?

I am trying to do a curved path animation on Android on canvas. I have to draw a scooter animation like drawing itself.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curved Path animations on Android are possible through PathInterpolator and PathInterpolatorCompat which is backward compatible, available in support library. But your question seems rather confusing to me if you want to draw a path of a scooter, then create a Path object containing the path coordinates of scooter then use Canvas.drawPath and draw that path. PathInterpolator is actually used for changing the path of animation during a translate or similar kind of animation which moves along a path. However, A better approach that I suggest is using a VectorDrawable and manipulating its trimStart and trimEnd properties to maintain how much path of scooter gets drawn.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I will use aforementioned styles. Apologies for not writing clearly my problem, what I want actually is that the path draw animation means it should draw as if someone is drawing with a pencil stroke kind of.... I think I'll use VectorDrawable

Comment: @user1503008 if you think the answer is right, you should mark it as accepted, so other people can also know.